# opendaylight how to configure ReceiveTimeout for CaptureSnapshotReply

Tags: opendaylight

I am facing the ReceiveTimeout while doing datastore backup using the rest utility provided by opendaylight.
However I am not able to manipulate this value to some more as it seems hardcoded in the Java code.
Can someone know where can this be modified and which field to modify it to more value.
Tried looking into "org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.cfg" but could not find any filed to modify this timeout.

Comment: can you post more details please? what is the full rest command you are using to issue a datastore backup? What is the full response/output/log messages/etc of the ReceiveTimeout?

Comment: https://localhost:8443/restconf/operations/cluster-admin:backup-datastore
this is the Rest call (calling via curl from the script)
Response is:
org.opendaylight.controller.sal-akka-raft - 1.4.2.Boron-SR2 | GetSnapshotReplyActor | member-1-shard-default-config: Got ReceiveTimeout for inactivity - did not receive CaptureSnapshotReply within 30000 ms"

This comes from the java code:
private Duration snapshotReplyActorTimeout = Duration.create(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Hardcoded in RaftActorSnapshotMessageSupport.

Comment: Also I am not sure if this timeout can be increased from some configuration settings, as I could not find a way to do that, please excuse my less knowledge in this area as I am new to it.

Comment: yeah, I am not sure you can change that timeout with a config setting. looks hardcoded. If that is really the problem (that you need more time) then the only option I can think of is to change the java code and rebuild the controller. That might be daunting if you are new to the process. However, 30s to receive a reply seems pretty long. Are you sure whatever problem you are working on is not something else?

Comment: Are there any parameters which can be modified and would help in waiting more..I could see that in Nitrogen version of ODL same code is there but may be some other optimizations helping there..as this issue not reproducing in Nitrogen version..Unfortunately this particular customer is still in Boron and may be there till next 2 months, so looking for a quick workaround if possible...

Comment: sorry, I really don't know. Boron is really old (5th release) and we are already moving on the 13th release (Aluminium) now.